# How to read S3 file only once in Apache Camel

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel, apache-camel-aws

My DSL start is something like this:

`from("aws-s3://" + s3_bucket_name + "?amazonS3Client=#amazonS3Client&deleteAfterRead=false&fileName=myfile.csv")`

after this I covert each row into a JSON file and dump into a local directory.

The problem is it keeps on doing this like its stuck in an infinite loop.

Any idea how I process the file only once and then stop?

Answer (score 1):

You can read this FAQ about how to stop a route from a route: http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html

Or instead of a route you use a `ConsumerTemplate` to poll the s3file only once.

Comment: Hi @claus : is it possible to provide any example/reference link which can explain use of `ConsumerTemplate` to achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Idempotent Consumer](http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html)

```
from("aws-s3://" + s3_bucket_name + "?amazonS3Client=#amazonS3Client&deleteAfterRead=false&fileName=myfile.csv")
.idempotentConsumer(header("CamelAwsS3Key"), idempotentRepository)
```

You can provide implementation of idempotentRepository based on your need as mentioned in above link.